# Apache Sqoop moved into the Attic in 2021-06

Tags: hadoop, rdbms, sqoop

I have installed hadoop version 3.3.1 and sqoop 1.4.7 which doesn't seem  compatible , I am getting depreciated API implemented error while importing rdbms table.

As I tried to google for compatible versions I found apache sqoop is moved to appache attiq .and version 1.4.7 which is last stable version states in its documentation says  that "  Sqoop is currently supporting 4 major Hadoop releases - 0.20, 0.23, 1.0 and 2.0. "

Would you please explain what does it mean and what should I do.
could you please suggest What are the alternatives of SQOOP .

Comment: Use Spark JDBC reader w/ HDFS or Hive writers instead - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Answer (score 2):

It means just what the [board minutes](https://whimsy.apache.org/board/minutes/Sqoop.html) say: Sqoop has become inactive and is now moved to the Apache Attic. This doesn't mean Sqoop is deprecated in favor of some other project, but for practical purposes you should probably not build new implementations using it.

Much of the same functionality is available in other tools, including other Apache projects. Possible options are Spark, Kafka, Flume. Which one to use is very dependent on the specifics of your use case, since none of these quite fill the same niche as Sqoop. The database connectivity capabilities of Spark make it the most flexible solution, but it also could be the most labor-intensive to set up. Kafka might work, although it's not quite as ad-hoc friendly as Sqoop (take a look at Kafka Connect). I probably wouldn't use Flume, but it might be worth a look (it is mainly meant for shipping logs).

Comment: Kafka brokers are not the same as Sqoop, at all

Comment: @OneCricketeer Both tools solve the same fundamental problem of moving data from source to target. But Kafka isn't really designed for bulk transfers and would still require a consumer so I can see your point. Still, there is nothing that directly replaces Sqoop, and we don't really know OP's use case, so we can't say with certainty what the right approach should be for their specific situation.

Comment: My point was that _Kafka Connect_ might be close, but HDFS connectivity nor JDBC functions are built into Kafka itself. Spark/Flink/Beam can all interface with all of JDBC and HDFS and Hive, so while there isn't a builtin CLI tool for import/export, I'd say it's the closest.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Agreed, that makes sense. I updated to reflect those points, and appreciate the input. To be fair, this was a comment that grew too long at 2AM while waiting for a batch job to finish :)

Comment: I learned several years ago that many of the Sqoop developers went to work on Streamsets, which is like Nifi. Both of those could work too

Comment: @OneCricketeer Streamsets is rubbish. We paid money for it, it completely failed to deliver and StreamSets refused to help. It was very slow and quite buggy. When it failed you'd have to restart every single job because they all ran in the same process. They promised a new version, which arrived after our licence expired, we evaluated it and it was just as slow.